# How to handle Backgrid.js cell edition requests

Tags: java, spring, backbone.js, backgrid

I am working with Backgrid these days.
Trying to edit a row value and to persist the database object, I end up with the following HTTP error:

> NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http:// localhost:8084/fsrtool/api/roles/5

My web application driven by a Java Spring backend. 
The Backgrid frontend is supposed to call the following method:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Override
public Role getById(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
    LOG.info("get a role with its ID");
    Role r = rds.getById(id);
    return r;
}
```

I know that my service class is working, because I am able to create new 'Roles' from the Backgrid table and thanks to the following method:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Override
public Response create(final Role r) {
    return Response.status(Status.CREATED).entity(rds.getOrSave(r)).build();
}
```

Investigating the problem, I figured out that backgrid sent the request with **PUT** method.
I then tried several changes into my service class in order to handle this request, but I have not been able to find the good way of setting this up.

Would you know how Backgrid cells should be edited?

Comment: I assume it's using basic RESTful services, in which I believe a PUT would be used for update an exiting value.  So, from what your describing, it seems like you should have a handler for `@PUT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as the application I'm working on seems to be designed, I actually was not using the good library...

The way I need my service method to be:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{id}")
public Response update(final Role r, @PathParam("id") Long id) {
    // do some processing... save to the db
}
```